# Recursive Function Not Returning Properly

Tags: javascript, ajax, recursion

I have a code as follows

```
function lp(p, list, count) {
    $.ajax({url: 'ajax.php', data: {id:p}, success: function (data) {
        // the ajax output an image's url, based on the id p
        if(p>count) {
            return list;
        } else {
            lp(p+1, list+'<img src="' + data + '"><br>', count);
        }
    }})
}
alert(lp(1,"",5));
```

The problem is, whenever I run the code, "undefined" always pop's out

So to solve my mystery, I added a few more lines to debug my code, and this is what I get

```
function lp(p, list, count) {
    $.ajax({url: 'ajax.php', data: {id:p}, success: function (data) {
        // the ajax output an image's url, based on the id p
        if(p>count) {
            alert("Done");
            return list;
        } else {
            alert("Entering phase " + p);
            lp(p+1, list+'<img src="' + data + '"><br>', count);
        }
    }})
}
alert(lp(1,"",5));
```

By changing into this, the result turned to to be "Undefined", then followed by the "Entering Phase X", then "Done", which means the first undefined is returned by the alert(lp) code, and before it actually went in and parse all the data inside the recursive function.

Is there a way I can force the script to wait until AJAX is done before parsing?

Edit: I've also tried changing

```
alert(lp(1,"",5));
```

into

```
list=lp(1,"",5);
alert(list);
```

Of course, that doesn't work either

Comment: `return lp(p+1, list+'<img src="' + data + '"><br>', count);`

Comment: For this to work in that manner you would need to use synchronous requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could add a callback to the function, as:

```
function lp(p, list, count, callback) {
    $.ajax({url: 'ajax.php', data: {id:p}, success: function (data) {
        // the ajax output an image's url, based on the id p
        if(p>count) {
            alert("Done");
            callback(list);
        } else {
            lp(p+1, list+'<img src="' + data + '"><br>', count, callback);
        }
    }})
}

lp(1,"",5, function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

the `alert(data);` is triggered when your ajax request completes

Comment: Thanks, never thought of using callback function, that sure brightens up a lot of different uses

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code is that $.ajax is an asynchronous function. Lp() will call $.ajax(), however, the success callback will not be invoked immediately. Instead your code will run $.ajax() and then reach the bottom of your Lp function (which does not return anything). When the server returns a response from the ajax call, the success callback will then be fired (but by then alert would have already displayed undefined.

The best solution would be the pass a callback in your lp function that will call alert when success is called:

```
function lp(p, list, count, callback) {
  $.ajax({url: 'ajax.php', data: {id:p}, success: function (data) {
      // the ajax output an image's url, based on the id p
      if(p>count) {
          callback(list);
      } else {
        lp(p+1, list+'<img src="' + data + '"><br>', count, callback);
      }
  }})
}
alert(lp(1,"",5), function(list) {
  console.log(list);
});
```